# Call SQL Stored Procedure with input "'abc','xyz'"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to call:

```sql
EXEC [MyProcedure] @@param=' ';
                           |.| =  'string1','string2','string3','string4'
             This is one string: |---------------------------------------|
```

How can I achieve this? Using `'''` didn't work for me.

```sql
--- This doesn't work:
EXEC [MyProcedure] @@param=''''string1','string2','string3','string4'''';
EXEC [MyProcedure] @@param='''string1','string2','string3','string4''';
```

Comment: Just to note semi-colon (`;`) is a statement terminator. You're doing it wrong to start a line with it.

Comment: @DaleK I was wondering about that. I've seen people use it in the beginning "just in case" a previous parallel query is in the same script, but ended up making this a habit. I'll edit it out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double up the single quotes inside the string:

```
EXEC [MyProcedure] @@param='''string1'',''string2'',''string3'',''string4''';
```

Comment: It's always the little things that we miss. Thanks for the answer! It works!